# Twitter and Pinterest social buttons parse on request

Tags: javascript, twitter, pinterest

I have the code that Twitter and Pinterest have supplied for Tweeting or Pinning an item on my page. Now this is running a little slow, mainly because of there is a lot of social buttons to parse, so i thought i'd do it when they were needed instead.

With Facebook's API i could do it like this to parse a specific snippet

```
FB.XFBML.parse($mysnippet);
```

How can i do the same with the Pinterest and Twitter buttons? I can't seem to find any methods for doing this manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter has a reparse function:

```
twttr.widgets.load();
```

Comment: I'm still digging around for a good Pinterest solution; their docs say there is nothing built-in to handle this.